# hook.useHook is not a function while implementing a new endpoint NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am running into the error `TypeError: hook.useHook is not a function` bellow.

I a desperate move I have placed many types as `any` but as you you guessed, this did not solved it.

[image: error]

Here is my `use-subscription.tsx` file

```
import ...

export type UseSubscribe<
    H extends MutationHook<any> = MutationHook<any>
    > = ReturnType<H['useHook']>

export const fetcher: HookFetcherFn<any> = mutationFetcher

const fn = (provider: Provider) => provider.subscriptions?.useSubscriptions!

const useSubscribe: any = (...args: any) => {
    const hook = useHook(fn)
    return useMutationHook({ fetcher, ...hook })(...args)
}

export default useSubscribe
```

I am not sure what the problem is, I even don't know what to look for if it's not about types, which I tried to change to `any`.

And here is the `use-hook.ts`

```
export function useFetcher() {
  const { providerRef, fetcherRef } = useCommerce()
  return providerRef.current.fetcher ?? fetcherRef.current
}

export function useHook<
  P extends Provider,
  H extends MutationHook<any> | SWRHook<any>
>(fn: (provider: P) => H) {
  const { providerRef } = useCommerce<P>()
  const provider = providerRef.current
  return fn(provider)
}

export function useSWRHook<H extends SWRHook<any>>(
  hook: PickRequired<H, 'fetcher'>
) {
  const fetcher = useFetcher()

  return hook.useHook({
    useData(ctx) {
      const response = useData(hook, ctx?.input ?? [], fetcher, ctx?.swrOptions)
      return response
    },
  })
}

export function useMutationHook<H extends MutationHook<any>>(
  hook: PickRequired<H, 'fetcher'>
) {
  const fetcher = useFetcher()

  return hook.useHook({
    fetch: useCallback(
      ({ input } = {}) => {
        return hook.fetcher({
          input,
          options: hook.fetchOptions,
          fetch: fetcher,
        })
      },
      [fetcher, hook.fetchOptions]
    ),
  })
}
```

If someone is interested in this issue, you can find more in https://github.com/vercel/commerce which I used as a based repo to create mine.

Comment: what is `useHook()`?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious here, but I don't see anything forcing `useHook` function to return an object containing `useHook` property. Can you try to check the type (list of keys) of the useMutationHook actual param?

Comment: As a sidenote, solving a _run-time_ error (that seems to be caused by type mismatch) by relaxing _compile-time_ type checks is never a good idea. Instead of adding `any` you should actually remove them, to help TS help you.

Comment: The useMutationHook type is in this file https://github.com/vercel/commerce/blob/main/framework/commerce/utils/types.ts.

Thanks for the advice I'll do that

Comment: I made a fork with the error https://github.com/vercel/commerce/pull/507